# Как обрабатывать аргументы командной строки в Delphi приложении?

Tags: windows, delphi, консоль

С помощью каких функций получать и обрабатывать аргументы передаваемые приложению через командную строку в Windows?

Тип приложения не важен (консольное или оконное).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аргументы доступны в функции `ParamStr()`.

Для их получения, достаточно вызвать эту функцию и передать в нее порядковый номер нужного аргумента (начинается с 1 и заканчивается `ParamCount`).

```
for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(I));
```

`ParamStr(0)` обычно содержит путь к исполняемому файлу (exe).

Пример, как это работает всё вместе:

```
C:\MyApp.exe -one -three
```

вызов приложения даст вот такие значения:

```
ParamStr(0) = C:\MyApp.exe
ParamStr(1) = -one
ParamStr(2) = -three
```

> Замечание: Если вы запустите приложение через `CreateProcess()`, укажите и имя приложения и командую строку, она в программу придет именно так, как будет указана в параметре `CreateProcess()`. Если вы там явно не пропишете имя приложения - его и не будет. Это поведение не зависит от языка и компилятора.

Comment: ParamStr(0) совершенно не обязательно содержит путь к приложению. Параметры командной строки формируются вызывающей стороной и она может туда записать что угодно, а не путь.

Comment: Если вы запустите приложение через CreateProcess(), укажите и имя приложения и командую строку, она в программу придет именно так, как будет указана в параметре CreateProcess(). Если вы там явно не пропишете имя приложения - его и не будет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы не против добавить этот комментарий в ответ?

Comment: Нет конечно :-) Это поведение не зависит от языка и компилятора, правда...

Comment: Немного в тему [INFO: Understanding CreateProcess and Command-line Arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/175986/info-understanding-createprocess-and-command-line-arguments)

Comment: вообще были ведь еще функции, которые парсили строку аргументов  и можно было получать значения по имени параметра и т.п., но что то не могу вспомнить как назывались.

Comment: @teran FindCmdLineSwitch ?

Comment: не, я было это написал сюда в коменты и удалил, она булевый результат возвращает, а я помню что конкретное значение по имени ключа было

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов "ParamStr(0) совершенно не обязательно содержит путь к приложению" и "Это поведение не зависит от языка и компилятора" - вы ошиблись. ParamStr(0) всегда содержит полное и абсолютное имя исполняемого модуля. По крайней мере, под Windows. Посмотрите сырцы: if Index = 0 then GetModuleFileName.

Comment: Лучше скажите про то, что в Delphi не поддерживаются кавычки в параметрах ни в каком виде (нет поддержки экранирования).

Comment: @Alex ох какие они молодцы-то! Мало того, что у них функция делает две разные вещи, так они еще зачем-то такой костыль вводят... Delphi - зло.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться маленькой библиотекой [delphi-argparse](https://github.com/tokibito/delphi-argparse).

Пример использования:

```
var
  Parser: TArgumentParser;
  ParseResult: TParseResult;
begin
  Parser := TArgumentParser.Create;
  try
    Parser.AddArgument('--foo', saBool); // --foo
    Parser.AddArgument('--bar', saStore); // --bar bar_value

    ParseResult := Parser.ParseArgs; // если аргумент опущен, используется ParamStr
    // ParseResult := Parser.ParseArgs(ListOfString);
    try
      ParseResult.HasArgument('foo'); // Вернёт True/False
      ParseResult.GetValue('bar'); // Вернёт bar_value в виде строки
    finally
      ParseResult.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Parser.Free;
  end;
end;
```